# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 using flutter on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

i'm new to flutter and i'm trying to run my application on android studio but i always get this error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1470)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1298)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:587)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:480)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:469)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:159)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1290)
        ... 16 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please, How can I fix this ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a minimal reproducible example (see stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with creating one), or at least some more context about what you are doing to trigger the error.

Comment: It looks like SSLHandshake failure. Please check if your system time is correct. If it is, try restarting android studio / vscode.

Comment: @Rahul I updated my system time and it worked. Thanks